# Expression Engine v4.3.8 thinks it is "up to date!" so no option to upgrade to 5.x

Tags: expressionengine

In brief the issue is that after upgrading from EE3 to EE4, when logging in to the admin panel the option to "upgrade" just says that it is "up to date!", even though version 5.x is available. How can I tell EE that it is not up to date so I can start the one click upgrade process as described here https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/updating.html?

> Just a note to say I have tried posting this on the official
>   Expression Engine forum but it is buggy and will not let me to properly create an account.
>   I am posting here as it seems I will have to tamper with some source code to fix the issue, but I would be happy if I'm wrong!

Further, I am running this on my local machine on localhost, would that makes any difference?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the fact that it doesn't show the available version number is due to the fact that the EE install can't communicate with the expressionengine website. This might be curl or firewall related since you are running the site locallly. I bet if you put it on a webserver somewhere it will work